# compare two arrays and show count of characters

Tags: c#, algorithm, pseudocode

I have two arrays:

```
 string[] array1 = {"a","b","c","d","e"}

 string[] array1 = {"x","y","a","b","a"}
```

I want to print the result like this:

```
a = 3
b = 2
c = 1
d = 1
e = 1
x = 1
y = 1
z = 1
```

I can run a loop inside the loop and find this out but is there a better way to achieve the same result?

I want to do this in plain C# without using LINQ.

Comment: share some of what you have, you may have the best solution but we will not know if you don't show us what you have done!  I will gladly upvote once you can provide a bit more.

Comment: Merge the 2 arrays and do a traditional group-by and count. Plenty of Q+A on that.

Comment: based on "compare two arrays and show count of COMMON characters" I would guess the result should be [a=3, b=2], since c,d,e,x,y are not common. Could you clarify the requirements?

Comment: @aiodintsov : thanks to point that out.

Comment: @Asdfg but what is the answer? is it going to include c, d, e, x, y or not? if it includes -> it's concat(array1,array2) -> histogram; if not then it is ar3 = intersect(array1,array2) -> histogram of (concat(array1,array2) over ar3). besides that what is the requirements? C# 2, C# 3, C# 4? ban on LINQ? ban on Array methods? etc.? Target framework 2.0, 3.0, 3.5, 4.0, 4.5?

besides you use chars, do you have to use strings? so could your arrays be {"aaa","word2","else"}? or they are indeed char arrays {'a','b','c'} only?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use LINQ to accomplish this:

```
var counts = array1.Concat(array2)
                  .GroupBy(v => v)
                  .Select(g => new { Value=g.Key, Number=g.Count() });

foreach(var item in counts.OrderBy(i => i.Value))
    Console.WriteLine("{0} = {1}", item.Value, item.Number);
```

---

Given that you want to avoid using LINQ and the extension methods for some reason, you could build your own dictionary:

```
var counts = new Dictionary<string, int>();
foreach(string item in array1)
{
    if (counts.ContainsKey(item))
        counts[item]++;
    else
        counts[item] = 1;
}
foreach(string item in array2)
{
    if (counts.ContainsKey(item))
        counts[item]++;
    else
        counts[item] = 1;
}

// Print out counts
foreach(var kvp in counts)
    Console.WriteLine("{0} = {1}", kvp.Key, kvp.Value);
```

Note that this doesn't sort the results - if you need them sorted, you'd have to do that as well.

Comment: i dont want to do it with LINQ. I just want to know how efficiently this can be done with just plain C#.

Comment: @Asdfg That wasn't specified - but is there a reason to avoid using LINQ?

Comment: @Asdfg LINQ is "just plain C#".  It's a part of the language; it's not an extension or external library/tool.

Comment: @Asdfg That is a completely different language - with a completely different set of libraries and rules.  That being said, I showed you another approach using looping and classes, and not using any functional code.

Comment: +1 for adapting to the added requirement offering a LINQ and a non-LINQ solution.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`Concat`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb302894.aspx), [`GroupBy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.groupby.aspx) and [`OrderByDescending`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.orderbydescending):

```
var both = array1.Concat(array2);
var groups = both.GroupBy(s => s).OrderByDescending(g => g.Count());
Console.Write(
    String.Join(
        Environment.NewLine, 
            groups.Select(g => String.Format("{0} = {1}", g.Key, g.Count()))));
```

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a job for Linq:

```
var charCounts = array1.Concat(array2)
                    .GroupBy(c=>c)
                    .Select(g=>new Tuple<char, int>(g.Key, g.Count());
                    .OrderBy(t=>t.Item1);

foreach(var result in charCounts)
   Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0} = {1}", t.Item1, t.Item2));
```

Answer (score 1):

Read through the two arrays and put them into one dictionary. Keys are the members in the array like "a", "b", etc. Values are integers as count. So, if a key, exists, you increment the count; otherwise put the key into dictionary with a value as 1.

Answer (score 0):

Well, most naive implementation based on type of string would be something like this:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string[] array1 = {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e"};
        string[] array2 = {"x", "y", "a", "b", "a"};

        var histogram = new Dictionary<string, int>();
        Fill(histogram, array1);
        Fill(histogram, array2);

        foreach (var p in histogram)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}={1}",p.Key,p.Value);
        }
    }

    private static void Fill(Dictionary<string, int> histogram, string[] a)
    {
        foreach (string s in a)
        {
            if (histogram.ContainsKey(s))
                histogram[s] += 1;
            else
                histogram[s] = 1;
        }
    }
}
```

which is build dynamic histogram, print.
another simple approach is like this, but it's of worse readability:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string[] array1 = {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e"};
        string[] array2 = {"x", "y", "a", "b", "a"};

        string [] concat = new string[array1.Length+array2.Length];
        Array.Copy(array1,concat,array1.Length);
        Array.Copy(array2,0,concat,array1.Length,array2.Length);
        Array.Sort(concat);

        int pos = 0;
        while(pos<concat.Length)
        {
            var cur = concat[pos];
            int count = 0;
            while ( (pos<concat.Length) && (concat[pos]==cur))
            {
                pos += 1;
                count += 1;
            }
            Console.WriteLine("{0}={1}",cur,count);
        }
    }
```

generally - concat, sort, histogram on sorted data.